# How to combine two arraylists into one arraylist and pass it to procedure

Tags: java, arraylist

I need your help and assistant in combining two arraylists into a new arraylist to be passed to a procedure. Once the user selected certificates from Type A list, they will be stored in:

```
private List<String> selectedTypeACertificates = new ArrayList<String>();
```

And once the user selected certificates from Type B, they will be stored in:

```
private List<String> selectedTypeBCertificates = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Now in the procedure I need to pass only two String variables. One is the Staff Code and the other is the selectedTypes for both Types A & B.

```
CallableStatement callableStatement =
    connection.prepareCall("{call processCertificates(?, ?)}");

callableStatement.setInt(1, Staff_Code);
callableStatement.setString   (2, ); //I need to pass selectedTypeBCertificates & selectedTypeACertificates
```

Comment: I don't know any really simple way, and I'm sure there is one, but you could just use a `for` loop and simply iterate across the lists and call the appropriate indexes.

Comment: Are you asking how to concatenate two lists, or how to pass a list to a stored procedure?

Comment: I am asking how to append two arraylists to a new one and to pass the new arraylist to the procedure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add all elements from both lists to a newly created one, and then use a `StringBuilder` to build a string in order to pass it to the procedure:

```
List<String> selectedCertificates = new ArrayList<String>();
selectedCertificates.addAll(selectedTypeACertificates);
selectedCertificates.addAll(selectedTypeBCertificates);

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (String cert : selectedCertificates)
{
    sb.append(cert);
    sb.append("','");
}

String certificatesString = sb.toString();
if(!certificatesString.isEmpty()) {
    certificatesString = "'" + certificatesString.substring(0, certificatesString.lastIndexOf(",")) + "'";
}
```

The last couple of lines are there to remove the trailing comma. Of course you might need to change this if the procedure expects the string in a different format.

Comment: Thanks manouti ... What I need is similar to what you have shared the code for. However, will this store each selected type in a separate row?

Comment: @Learner30 I changed the code a bit... Maybe it's better to only add single quotes around the _whole_ string, not around each element. How the string is added to the table depends on what the stored procedure does.